# Can Guice inject something that requires a lookup function?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Guice in a Restlet web server, and there's one pattern I can't figure out: how to inject objects that are specific to a certain user or a certain request.

Say we have a request to list all the Widgets that belong to a project.  The service that looks up Widgets requires a Project instance.  There are many Projects in the system.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
public class WidgetResource extends ServerResource {

    //path: project/{project}/widgets

    private final WidgetService service;
    private final ProjectLookup projectLookup;

    @Inject
    public WidgetResource(WidgetService service, ProjectLookup projectLookup) {
        this.service = service;
        this.projectLookup = projectLookup;
    }

    @Get
    public WidgetCollection getWidgets() {
        String projectName = getAttribute("project"); //restlet lookup of path var
        Project project = projectLookup.get(projectName);
        WidgetCollection widgets = service.getWidgetsFor(project);
        return widgets;
    }

}
```

This works well enough, but it's clumsy, and I hope there's a better way.  It would be great to inject the correct Project object directly.  Is there a way to do this?

So far I've explored AssistedInject, which gives a factory object very similar to my Lookup.   I came close to an answer with custom annotations/injections, but dead-ended because the Restlet attributes map isn't populated until after injection. Have read the GitHub docs and the User's Guide.  Can't spot anything.

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
public class WidgetResource extends ServerResource {

    private final WidgetService service;

    @Inject
    public WidgetResource(WidgetService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Inject
    @Get
    public WidgetCollection getWidgets(@PathName("project") Project project) {
        WidgetCollection widgets = service.getWidgetsFor(project);
        return widgets;
    }
```

with (of course) a @Provides method in the configuration that would look up the path variable and use the lookup.  However, I can't figure out a way to hand a provider method the path name or the Resource instance as variables. Is this possible?  Any help appreciated!

Comment: I actually prefer the first version for readability!

Answer (score 0):

To your vision: You can not inject into "getWidgets" ... injection happens the very moment your widgetResource is created, so basically once your application/server starts.

Besides that, it looks perfectly fine. You have a REST resource that takes a project parameter and uses a service to look up widgets.

If you know all possible project names in advance, you could use guice' [mapBinder](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/git-history/504d6c3465f73e3420fc3723db99a37f741ac2c7/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) instead of the service.

```
public class WidgetsModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, WidgetCollection> mapbinder
        = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, WidgetCollection.class);
     mapbinder.addBinding("project1").toInstance(...);
     mapbinder.addBinding("project2").toProvider(...);
     mapbinder.addBinding("project3").to(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't disagree with you -- the first code example is simple enough.  The problem is that we have an elaborate system of lookups and object trees that vary by "project" or by "user", etc. And because the lists are dynamic by design (projects get added, deleted, changed) I can't figure a way to delegate their creation to Guice, and we must inject many clumsy lookup objects.  Since this is a repeated and troublesome pattern in the code, I was hoping there'd be a way around it.